# gulp-sass: how to disable adding of prefixes path of background-image

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

**Hello to everyone!**

I'm developing a web app, and using gulp-sass to compile my files into css.

**Schematic Project structure:**

```
build/
  -image.png
  -build.css
src/
  -app/
     -component_1/
        -component.scss
```

**Inside component.scss:**

```
div.component {
  background: url("/image.png") no-repeat center center;
}
```

**Here is my gulp script, responsible for the compiling sass into css:**

```
 gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src("src/app/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./sass.compiled/"))
    .pipe(concatCss("build.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
```

As the result: gulp-scss prepends background's url property with the path: 'component_1'. So instead of expected:

```
background: url("/image.png") no-repeat center center;
```

I get:

```
background: url("component_1/image.png") no-repeat center center;
```

Is there a way, I could make gulp-sass to prevent such behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `gulp-sass` that is causing this, but `gulp-concat-css`. As the [package description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat-css) states:

> Concatenates css files, bubbling up @import statements (as per the standard), and **optionally rebasing urls** and inlining local @import statements.

You need to disable the optional url rebasing. You can do so using the [`rebaseUrls` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat-css#api):

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src("src/app/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./sass.compiled/"))
    .pipe(concatCss("build.css", { rebaseUrls: false }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!